# how to tie text height to bounding box in fabricJS textbox

Tags: canvas, fabricjs

https://i.stack.imgur.com/WXkrG.jpg

So im working with fabricjs textboxes and i have a custom implementation that allows for textwrapping while still allowing the user to adjust the height of the bounding box. the problem is that the hidden bounding box for the text itself does not match up with the visibly draggable object box (See link above for example). It seems to only scale 50% of however far i reduce the size of the box. My objective is to have vertical text overflow just not show past the bottom of the bounding box. Its kind of happening as is but with the wrong scaling not matching up as i said. so how can i get that hidden box value to match the visible bounding box?

http://jsfiddle.net/L3xh06c5/

Here is a fiddle with the custom object implementation im working with

```
// initialize fabric canvas and assign to global windows object for debug
this.canvas = new fabric.Canvas("c", {
                                        selection: false,
                                        backgroundColor: '#fff',
                                        preserveObjectStacking: true,
                                        uniScaleTransform: true, });


fabric.ClueTextbox = fabric.util.createClass(fabric.Textbox, {
        type: 'cluetextbox',
         /**
         * Properties which when set cause object to change dimensions
         * @type Object
         * @private
         */
        _dimensionAffectingProps: 
fabric.IText.prototype._dimensionAffectingProps.slice(0),
    });

    var newItem = new fabric.ClueTextbox("Clue Text will appear here, with the same properties as this display text, bounded by this box... Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum eget mauris in eros efficitur sodales vel eu lectus. Curabitur dui felis, posuere non urna at, rhoncus efficitur ipsum.")
            newItem.set({
                fontSize: 40,
                lineHeight: 1,
                charSpacing: 10,
                editable: false,
                lockUniScaling: false,
                lockScalingFlip: true,
            });
            newItem.setControlsVisibility({
                mt: false, // middle top disable
                mb: false, // midle bottom
                ml: false, // middle left
                mr: false, // middle right
            });
            newItem.on('scaling',  () => {
                var newHeight = newItem.height * newItem.scaleY;
                newItem.set({
                    width: newItem.width * newItem.scaleX,
                    scaleX: 1,
                });
                newItem.initDimensions();
                newItem.set({ height: newHeight, scaleY: 1 })
            });

             this.canvas.add(newItem);
```

// ADD YOUR CODE HERE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution. I rewrite the `_renderTextCommon`

```js
/**
 * fabric.js template for bug reports
 *
 * Please update the name of the jsfiddle (see Fiddle Options).
 * This templates uses latest dev verison of fabric.js (https://rawgithub.com/kangax/fabric.js/master/dist/fabric.js).
 */

// initialize fabric canvas and assign to global windows object for debug
this.canvas = new fabric.Canvas("c", {
                                            selection: false,
                                            backgroundColor: '#fff',
                                            preserveObjectStacking: true,
                                            uniScaleTransform: true, });


fabric.ClueTextbox = fabric.util.createClass(fabric.Textbox, {
            type: 'cluetextbox',
             /**
             * Properties which when set cause object to change dimensions
             * @type Object
             * @private
             */
            _dimensionAffectingProps: fabric.IText.prototype._dimensionAffectingProps.slice(0),
            
            _renderTextCommon: function(ctx, method) {
                ctx.save();
                var lineHeights = 0, left = this._getLeftOffset(), top = this._getTopOffset(),
                    offsets = this._applyPatternGradientTransform(ctx, method === 'fillText' ? this.fill :        this.stroke);
                for (var i = 0, len = this._textLines.length; i < len; i++) {
                  var heightOfLine = this.getHeightOfLine(i),
                      maxHeight = heightOfLine / this.lineHeight,
                      leftOffset = this._getLineLeftOffset(i);
                  if(lineHeights+heightOfLine < this.getScaledHeight()){
                  this._renderTextLine(
                    method,
                    ctx,
                    this._textLines[i],
                    left + leftOffset - offsets.offsetX,
                    top + lineHeights + maxHeight - offsets.offsetY,
                    i
                  );
                  }
                  lineHeights += heightOfLine;
                }
                ctx.restore();
              }
        });
        
        var newItem = new fabric.ClueTextbox("Clue Text will appear here, ")
                newItem.set({
                    fontSize: 40,
                    lineHeight: 1,
                    charSpacing: 10,
                    editable: false,
                    dirty:false,
                    objectCaching:false,
                    lockUniScaling: false,
                    lockScalingFlip: true,
                });
                newItem.setControlsVisibility({
                    mt: false, // middle top disable
                    mb: false, // midle bottom
                    ml: false, // middle left
                    mr: false, // middle right
                });
                newItem.on('scaling',  () => {
                    var newHeight = newItem.height * newItem.scaleY;
                    newItem.set({
                        width: newItem.width * newItem.scaleX,
                        scaleX: 1,
                    });
                    newItem.initDimensions();
                    newItem.set({ height: newHeight, scaleY: 1 })
                });
                
                 this.canvas.add(newItem);
// ADD YOUR CODE HERE
```

```css
canvas {
    border: 1px solid #999;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://rawgit.com/kangax/fabric.js/master/dist/fabric.js"></script>
<canvas id="c" width="600" height="600"></canvas>
```